# Interpreted MATLAB Function block error in simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I create simulink block like below:

[image]

inside Interpreted MATLAB Function i use this code.

```
function y1 = fcn(signal)
%% variable declaration
Fm = 100;%length of Frames excursion
framelnc = 100;%length of Frames excursion
Fn = 256;%length of Frames sampling frequency 12.500kHz, frame length 020.5ms
fs = 8000;

x=signal;

%% Preprocessing: Noise Removal
IS= 0.25; % initial silence (noise only)
output=denoise(x,fs,IS);
y = output;

%% Extraction of LFCC Features
feat = lfcc(y,fs);

%% Extract VQ CODE
k=16; % number of centroids required

code1 = vqext(feat, k);
test = mean2(code1);

%% Emotions Recognition 
load ('train.mat')

Class = knnclassify(test , feature, type);

if (Class == 1)
   %% Display identification results
   msg=1;
end

if (Class == 2)
   %% Display identification results
    msg=2;
end

y1 = msg;
```

I defined these `denoise`,`lfcc`,`vqext`,`knnclassify` function in separate matlab files. but I got error like below.

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At your picture we can see that formally your data has two dimensions [1024x1] ! So I think, that Interpreted MATLAB Function can't operate with this data type.

So I suggest to use Frame Conversion block.

P.S. Be the way, why are you use Interpreted function? is it really necessary?

> Note   This block is slower than the Fcn block because it calls the
>   MATLAB parser during each integration step. Consider using built-in
>   blocks (such as the Fcn block or the Math Function block) instead.
>   Alternatively, you can write the function as a MATLAB S-function or
>   MEX-file S-function, then access it using the S-Function block.

Comment: Thankyou @ Mikhail_Sam

Comment: another problem i found is load the mat file. it loads into the work space only. i solve by dataset=load('train.mat');
feature=dataset.feature;
type=dataset.type;

Comment: @ Mikhail_Sam i want to run this model in raspberry pi without using pc. i have multiple .m files for interpreted matlab function. can you help me?

Comment: really I have no experience of using raspberry pi, but we can try, of course - using .mat files in matlab and simulink is a common practice. But I recommend you to open new question about your exactly problem - me and a lot of people will help you!

Comment: @ Mikhail_Sam here i have lot of matlab functions(denoise, lfcc,vqext) in different files within Interpreted function. can i use MATLAB S-function in this situation ?

Comment: I'm not really sure you can do it with Interpreted function (need to check) but anyway you can do it with S-functions.

Comment: @ Mikhail_Sam when i use Interpreted function i face this problem (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704697/run-simulink-block-on-raspberry-pi). when i use S-functions is this error happen?